# Rails 3 - Devise User has_many privately nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid

I got a real head scratcher here and I am in need of some direction. What do you do when you want a devise User to have nested objects of their own, not viewable nor accessible to other users? For instance: User has_many Customers which has_many Jobs. I can get User authentication to work and I can get Customers > Jobs nesting to work separately. Now, how do I get a user that has_many customers that has_many jobs?

What is the modern and efficient way to accomplish this problem with Devise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about the User model that is generated by devise. You are free to add has_many customers to it. [This railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1?view=asciicast) show how to integrate omniauth with devise and it includes changing the user model.

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to have any good resources doing something like this?

Comment: I saw something that can get you started. I've added to the answer